# echo from sql to table

Tags: php, sql, select, html-table, echo

I need to select some data from mysql and echo them into a table,
I have 20 entries which I want to echo them into 5by4 table I can select them like this:

```php
<?php
         $sql = "SELECT player FROM `prize` WHERE inviter='$player'";
         $result = $conn->query($sql);
         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

         ?>
         <table style="width: 100%;border:1px">
         <tr> <td class="auto-style3">
<?php

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

                    <?php echo "<br>". $row["player"].""; ?>
<?php
}} 

         ?>


   </td>  </tr>   </table>
```

it gives me something like this:

[image]

but I want it like this:

[image]

Can anyone  help?

Comment: add a counter end and start a row (<tr>) after every 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this, using $count to count your item in array. and after 5 items have been echoed, then you put `<tr>` to echo in new row

```
<?php
  $count=0;
  echo "<table>";
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($count==0) {
      echo "<tr>";
    }
    $count++;
    echo "<td>".$row["player"]."</td>";
    if($count==5) {
      echo "</tr>";
      $count=0;
    }
  }   
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to add a counter and close the  tag every five records, this is the result:

```html
<?php
         $sql = "SELECT player FROM `prize` WHERE inviter='$player'";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   
   ?>
   <table style="width: 100%;border:1px">
   <tr>
           <?php

                $counter=0;
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if($counter == 4){
                   echo '</tr><tr>';
                   $counter=0;
                }
            ?>

              <td><?php echo $row["player"].""; ?></td>

            <?php

              $counter++;

            }} 

           ?> 
       
        
   </tr>   </table>
```